# NetSuite - Payment of Bills in Multi-Currencies

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Our EUR bank account needs to process payment of bills in multi-currencies. Apparently this feature is not available within NetSuite at this moment.

There is an enhancement - **Transactions>Purchases/Vendors>Pay Bills - if account currency is not the base currency - list of bills will only show those with the same currency**.

The alternative work around is to create a fake clearing account and then create double journal entries for each transaction and move funds around the accounts. This would work but the sheer number of transactions we'd have to process means this solution is not feasible.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Could we possibly create SuiteScript to overcome this default NetSuite behaviour? Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Looking around help I found 'Multiple Currencies and Vendors' https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N1400742.html.  Although this is probably a NetSuite OneWorld feature.  Do you have a OneWorld account?

Comment: Thanks for the link. So that's more about being able to work with vendors with multiple currencies. My issue is more around the chart of accounts. In making Vendor Payments, users are able to only select Bank Accounts having the same currency as the Vendor or the Company's base currency. It seems a Vendor record has to have the same currency as the Bank Account so that they may be pulled when making a payment through the Bills Payment page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple currency to a vendor records same for customers. This will allow you to select accounts based on those currencies. Note that bank account can have only one currency.

Comment: I believe NetSuite's ability to complete cross-currency reconciliations without the need for additional steps is a limitation. Ex: paying a USD bill using EURO bank account - then unable to mark that USD bill as paid against the the EURO account within the "Bill Payments" section of NetSuite.